# setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I've been researching my problem and don't want to post a duplicate but I have tried the methods as described in my research and cannot get my function to delay!!

Can someone take a look and let me know if there is something wrong with my syntax and why it's not functioning? Everything runs good except for the setTimeout function

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true
    });

    $("#prevBtn a").hide();
    $("#nextBtn a").hide();
    $("#slider").mouseover(function(){
        $("#prevBtn a").show();
        $("#nextBtn a").show();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#prevBtn a").fadeOut('slow');
        $("#nextBtn a").fadeOut('slow');
    },3000);
});
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Your setimeout function works. I put a console.log('hi') inside and i saw it.

Comment: You're hiding `#prevBtn a` and `#nextBtn a` and then fading them out in setTimeout, you probably meant to use fadeIn (http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: I don't want the buttons to show on load that's why I have them hidden on load. When the user mouseover the slider the buttons then appear. On mouse out I would like the buttons to fade out after 3 seconds..

Comment: .delay only works for 1.4. I'm not using that

Comment: @user1609481 It was **added** in 1.4 : http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true
    });

    $("#prevBtn a").hide();
    $("#nextBtn a").hide();
    $("#slider").mouseover(function(){
        $("#prevBtn a").show();
        $("#nextBtn a").show();
    })
    .mouseout(function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#prevBtn a").fadeOut('slow');
            $("#nextBtn a").fadeOut('slow');
        },3000);

    });

});
```

Comment: Agreed. I didn't try to optimize at all because we don't know what his html looks like.

Comment: Hi Geuis. Your solution did the trick. I could not find that anywhere in my research. Thank you and everyone for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your setimeout function works. I put a

```
console.log('hi');
```

inside and i saw it.

I think  you need to remove these lines, because it will make the element hidden on dom ready.

```
$("#prevBtn a").hide();
$("#nextBtn a").hide();
```